# group select a links in css

Tags: css

So simple question, how can i select/style a set of links inside a div using one line of
code.

for example, say i have a div called ABC, and i wanted to style the a:visited property and give it a white color then id do something like,

```
#ABC a:visited{ //color:#fff } etc
```

but i want to style all of the a properties like visited,link,hover etc...in one line as oppose to doing

```
#ABC a:visited{ //color:#fff }
#ABC a:hover{ //color:#fff }
#ABC a:link{ //color:#fff }
#ABC a:active{ //color:#fff }
```

because for example, i dont want to style the documents links site wide, only within
a certain div and i dont want to write it all out...im aware i could just copy paste but

just wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple CSS selectors

```
#ABC a:visited, #ABC a:link, #ABC a:active, #ABC a:hover { color: #fff; }
```

Comment: thanks, i knew this....i MUST be tired..i look at this and im like "wtf i already have this on my code, why is it not working " and forgot to add the "ABC to the rest of them...lol thanks

Comment: No problem, I once did the same :)